# How to reference invalid property in object?

Tags: c#

Sorry, If this question seems too broad, but I'm a little unsure how I should do this task.

I have some objects:

```
public class A
{
    public B b {get;set;}
    public C[] cList {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public string val1 {get;set;}
}

public class C
{
    public string val2 {get;set;}
}
```

And a set of validators:

```
public class AValidator : IValidator<A>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(A obj){...}
}

public class BValidator : IValidator<B>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(B obj){...}
}

public class CValidator : IValidator<C>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(C obj){...}
}
```

Error looks like this:

```
public class ValidationError
{
    public int Code {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

I perform validation like this:

```
_validator.Validate(new A()).ThrowIfInvalid();
```

But here is the problem, how to reference invalid property and Serialize/Deserialize this reference to use it on client?

For example, if `new A().c[2].val2` is invalid, I should be able to obtain this path on server and use it on client for my view (obtain PropertyInfo, and object).

Is there some extensions/libraries in C# which provide serializable references for properties? For example, like XPath in XML.

Comment: You can use reflection to [get property value by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1196991/1997232). Otherwise your question is offtopic (asking for a library).

Comment: Why would it be invalid if you would validate it with correct object. You need design patterns to structure your classes. Check out Abstract factory, factory and bridge to check which will suit your scenario.http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Comment: I meant invalid in my business case. For example if name of person was provided as "sh*thead", I should rise validation error. Either way it is not part of the question.

Comment: Create a get; set; and define validation which you call and throw some custom business error

Comment: Umm, what is it supposed to mean? How it is related to question? Im not asking of how I should implement getter and setter, Im asking how I should refrence property of some object.

Answer (score 0):

Extend class `ValidationError` with `PropertyPath` property and prepend it on each parent validator

```
public class AValidator : IValidator<A>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(A obj)
    {
        if(obj.b == null)
            yield return new ValidationError {Message = "b is null", PropertyPath = "a.b"};
        else
        { 
            var bresults = new BValidator().Validate(obj.b);
            foreach(var result in bresults)
            {
                result.PropertyPath = "a.b." + result.PropertyPath;
                yield return result;
            }
        }
...
            var cresults = new BValidator().Validate(obj.c[i]);
            foreach(var result in cresults)
            {
                result.PropertyPath = "a.c[i]." + result.PropertyPath;
                yield return result;
            }
    }        
}
```